# Android - Error with registerReceiver ... WifiManager

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, wifimanager

Dears,

I'm working on a service (for old Android versions) that react on incoming SMS and should offer information about wifis detected.

The main class is '

> public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver

where is declared:

> private Context recContext;

Inside its 'Onreceive' is the code for catching the different incoming SMS. When the incoming SMS has the appropiate character is created the WifiManger:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){


    ......
    recContext = context;
    .........
    case wifilist:
        .........
        'wifimanager = (WifiManager) recContext.getSystemService(recContext.WIFI_SERVICE);' 
        ........
        SendLoc();
        .........
```

}

'SendLoc' is method of IncomingSMs with the following code:

```
private void SendLoc() {

....
case wifilist:
            if (wifimanager.isWifiEnabled()) {
                    ....
                    scanWifiNetworks();
        ....}
   ...}
```

And 'scanWifiNetworks()' is another method of IncomingSMs with the following code:

```
 private void scanWifiNetworks(){
        if(wifimanager.startScan()){

            try{
            recContext.registerReceiver(wifi_receiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));}
            catch(Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(recContext, "catch de register receiver", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

The code for the wifi_receiver is inside too IncomingSMs class:

```
BroadcastReceiver wifi_receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
...

    public void onReceive(Context recontext, Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(recContext, "A onReceive ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       ...}
```

}

No matter with the different code in the OnReceive method of 'BroadcastReceiver wifi_receiver', 'recContext.registerReceiver(wifi_receiver, ...' always crash and is called the message of the catch exception.

I've tried the same code for wifi detection called from a button inside an Activity and it works right. So I'm sure I have the correct permissions. Maybe it is not possible to create a receiver inside another BroadcastReceiver class, or there is a context problem?

Comment: Add the stack trace of crash .

Comment: Thanks ADM, here you are the trace of the exception:

android.content.ReceiverCallNotAllowedException: IntentReceiver components are not allowed to register to receive intents
 at android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:147)
 at android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:141)
 at com.example.myself.serviceexample.IncomingSms.scanWifiNetworks(IncomingSms.java:261)
 at com.example.myself.serviceexample.IncomingSms.EnviaLocalitzacio(IncomingSms.java:407)
 at com.example.myself.serviceexample.IncomingSms.onReceive(Incom....

Comment: Thanks ADM, I've searched for the error information and I've found that 'recContext.registerReceiver(wifi_receiver, new IntentFilter(Wifi...' should be changed to 'recContext.getApplicationContext.registerReceiver(wifi_receiver, new IntentFilter(Wifi' . Now it works fine.